# RegEx Help.. something wrong in my pattern

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex, string

I'm looking to match this pattern:

```
 ((##.##.##))
```

Any series of Numbers/Decimals, surrounded by "((" and "))", and preceded by one whitespace

There can't be any characters in the middle except digits and periods.

Right now I have

```
"\s(\(){2}[\d\.]+(\)){2}"
```

but i'm not getting any matches...

Comment: well it works, at least in javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/73Bsp/

Comment: This seems correct, though you can simplify it to ` \\(\\(([\d.]+)\\)\\)`

Answer (score 1):

```
\s\(\([[.]|\d]+\)\)
```

seems to work. As a Java String that looks like this.

```
\\s\\(\\([[.]|\\d]+\\)\\)
```

You can test regular expressions online at various sites like http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html.

Maybe it will work in VB too.. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape the period inside `[]` braces. Try this:

```
\s\(\([.\d]+\)\)
```